# ¿Como llamo un archivo de javascript en mi sitemaster? C#

Tags: javascript, c#

Como mando llamar un archivo .js desde mi site master para que sea lo primero en ejecutarse dentro de mi aplicacion.

Codigo de SiteMaster:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="sitemaster.master.cs" Inherits="sitemaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("login.js") %>"></script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Codigo de JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    alert("Entro al JS");

});
```

Pero al correr la aplicacion no me sale ningun mensaje. Y la ubicacion del archivo es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien eh usado de la siguiente forma la linea de mi script en el sitemaster:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/login.js") %>"></script>
```

Pero ninguna de las dos formas me ha funcionado. Otra de las opciones que use fue la clasica:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"></script>
```

Tambien agregue jquery a mi codigo del sitemaster, lo añadi arriba en el head y la llamada a mi archivo .js lo llame al final de mi body:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Si agrego las lineas de codigo de jquery y javascript directamente en mi aspx (la vista) de manera tradicional funciona correctamente, pero en el sitemaster lo hago en el mismo orden los dos links de script pero no me manda el mensaje.

Codigo de login.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Hola Mundo"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Flxtr uso WebForms

Comment: ¿Podrias publicar tu pagina login.aspx? o por lo menos las primeras 5 lineas.

Comment: @danMiranda ya lo publique

Comment: actualize mi respuesta con mas datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hace falta la referencia a **jQuery**, agregala después de title.

Yo puse una que apunta a Google, reemplazala y utiliza la de tu instalación local de jQuery.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="sitemaster.master.cs" Inherits="sitemaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

// Agrega aqui tu link a jQuery
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("login.js") %>"></script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

También es necesario que modifiques tu login.aspx por algo como esto:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="login" MasterPageFile="~/sitemaster.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
<!-- Aqui van los CSS, JS y demas de tu pagina login-->
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <div>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Las **MasterPages** son plantillas en las cuales defines  que serán llenados por las páginas que utilizen la MasterPage como plantilla.

En el ejemplo de arriba se agrego el MasterPageFile para obligar a login.aspx a usar el master page.

Para probar tienes que correr la aplicacion e ir a login.aspx y entonces el MasterPager aparecera con el contenido de login.aspx.

Comment: te falto "type="text/javascript", aunque no se si es del todo obligatorio, pero me marcaba una advertencia, pero aun asi no me sale el mensaje de el alerta.

Answer (score 0):

creo que solo necesitas colocar la ruta física en la que se encuentra tu js. 
Te recominedo cargarlo antes de cerrar la etiqueta del body.
Saludos!.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="sitemaster.master.cs" Inherits="sitemaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>


<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hay un problema con tu respuesta, login.js no esta dentro de App_Code. nunca encontraria la ruta.

Comment: Gracias por notarlo, ya lo ví y lo corregí. Saludos!